# Store objects of two subclasses in the same Vector/List

Tags: java, list, oop, object, subclass

I am currently working on a basic Disc information management system for a school project in which a user can add/remove disc information. There are two types of discs that are mentioned in the specs, Music and Game. These both have some shared attributes and so I made a superclass called `Disc` that had two subclasses `Music` and `Game` discs that would inherit these shared attributes. The specs also state that there needs to be a single maintainable list for both types of disc, so regardless of whether the user chooses to add music or game it will be added to a single `DiscInfo` list.

My question is, how can I define a list of two objects? Are objects of a subclass also objects of the superclass and so I could create a list of `Disc` objects in which either `Music` or `Game` objects can be added/removed?

I'm brand new to OOP and so my understanding of classes and objects is very rudimentary and I may be thinking of this wrong. Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: A `List<Disc>` may contain both `Music` and `Game` objects, if this is your question.

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking, thanks!

Comment: And when reading, either use typechecks like `getClass()` or `instanceof` to be able to handle specifics. Or, you create an `enum` like so: `public enum DiscType {MUSIC, GAME}` and have that as an additional member variable in the `Disc` class. This combined with a `switch` statement is usually fastest if you have to discern between many subclasses, and it's also a lot easier and more portable than the typechecks.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of your list is known you can use an array type, but you can use List or vector too. Thanks to polymorphism you can put any children type from `Disc` into `List<Disc>`